# Can I make a google chrome tab background transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, web

I want to build a browser based snipping tool. My initial idea is to create a temporary window or popup that can be resized that has a transparent background. The screenshot will capture what is in the bounds of the window/popup and is seen through the transparent section.

It is really easy to build a transparent window of a local app:
[example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylVvP.png)
Is it even possible to do a clear background

Answer (score 0):

if i tell you that it is impossible, you will be sad, but it is realy impossible because there is no api to this work and html,javascript,css and some other languages are not much intelligent, how much you want so in small sentence this is impossible